# Back Button & iFrame for Android - Help a noob

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, cordova

I've seen there are a lot of answers about my problem but nothing works and I'm going mad.

I've a real simple iframe structure, what I want is that Back Button doesnt come back (page by page) but close app (hide or close is the same).

Think I'm really newbie, so please explain me everything step by step

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {

        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="content">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="content">
                    <iframe src="home.html" name="pagina" class="pagina"> </iframe>
                </div>
```

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
       if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
           e.preventDefault();
           navigator.app.exitApp();
       }
       else {
           navigator.app.backHistory()
       }
    }, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried before but it always come back page by page, not closing the app :(

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue initially i am fed up. But after many iterations I have succeeded. Here is the snippet, add this in .run function of your app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup) {
      $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
        if(0){
          navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else {
          navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
      }, 101);
})
```

In the above code 101 is the priority. For exitting the app the priority is 100. so we are increasing the priority to 101.